Filter rows with same values for two specific columns in R?
I have a tibble in R like:
df1<-tibble(student=c("John", "John", "John", "Mark", "June"), 
       grade=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A"), 
       age=c(18,16, 14, 19, 20), 
       city=c("Chicago", "Seattle", "LA", "SF", "LA"))

If two rows have the same values for "Student" and "Grade", I want to remove all but one of those rows. I do NOT want to just eliminate duplicate rows, as I only am focusing on two specific columns.
For example, the first three rows have the same value for "Student" and "Grade." I want to remove all these rows but ONE, so that there are not multiple rows with the same values for these two columns. My ideal output would be something like:
df2<-tibble(student=c("John", "Mark", "June"), 
            grade=c("A", "B", "A"), 
            age=c(18, 19, 20), 
            city=c("Chicago", "SF", "LA"))

Is there any way to do this in R?

distinct(df1, student, grade, .keep_all = TRUE)?

@Edward you are right my question is very similar to that one
